# How do i embed a hyperlink to a voice channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do i create an embed which mentions a voice channel.
I have seen this working in a discord server and i want to implement it into my bot.
I want the link to be clickable and when you click you are joining the mentioned voice channel.

I have tried <#channelid> but it just types out the name of the channel, it does not become a link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a link containing the `server id` and `channel id`

For example:

https://discordapp.com/channels/SERVERID/CHANNELID

You can add `[LINK](https://discordapp.com/channels/SERVERID/CHANNELID)` to get this => [LINK](https://discordapp.com/SERVERID/CHANNELID)

Comment: Bonus question: do you know how to link to a dm channel ?

Comment: You make the server id `@me` and you can find out the id for the desired DM channel via e.g. inspect element. And also the link in this answer is wrong, the link should be `https://discordapp.com/channels/SERVER/CHANNEL`.

Answer (score 7):

Apperantly, and I don't know if this is new or not, but just like mentioning a `#text-channel` it's possible to mention a **`#!`**`voice-channel`.

Answer (score 0):

To mention a text or voice channel you can use `<#YOUR_CHANNEL_ID>`. This will mention the channel, when clicking on it you'll automatically join the voice channel or open the text channel. (You can use this just in the embed's description or send it as a message without embed)